# Open source user tracking on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, tracking

I would like to track certain actions (e.g. how often an app is used) without using solutions from companies such as Pinch Media or Admob.

Do you know any open source project, which I could use as a starter for my own system?

Comment: What's wrong with their solutions?  They make their SDK available for use for free, and even provide the server infrastructure for you.

Comment: Brad, nothing is wrong with their solutions. However, I need own tracking code for the following reasons: Firstly, I don't want to collect too much information and don't want to touch my users' privacy (see current discussions on the web about Pinch Media's privacy issues). Secondly, I want to have an own tracking server for customized data analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Check these guys out: http://www.appads.com/

I think you can probably just use this, which is open source, with your own server: http://docs.appads.com/Open_Ad_Integration rather than using their service (which is limited beta anyway and may not be available to you).